# Calculus about basic integrals

Tags: calculus, integration

[image]

I have to find the lower and upper estimation. ( Hint = you should sketch a possible graph and draw the rectangles.)

My answer for the upper estimation was : 2( 23+15+6+33) = 154 
and My answer for the lower estimation was : 2( 12+23+15+6) = 112

But they were wrong, are these the upper and lower ? or the left and right hand sum ?

Later, I tried to draw the sketch and ended up with having only the first rectangle lower than the curve so I changed my answer for the lower estimation to 2(12) = 24 but it was wrong too.

Could anyone help get through it :)

Comment: Why have you taken $15$ as the lower value (and $6$ as the upper value) on the interval $(6,8)$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Lower and upper estimation are different left- and right-hand estimation. You did correct left-hand and right-hand estimation. For lower-estimation, look at the end-points on either side of a given interval, and take the lower value. For upper-estimation, look at the end-points on either side of a given interval, and take the higher value.
Higher:
$$[2,4]: [12,23] -> 23$$
$$[4,6]: [23,15] -> 23$$
Lower:
$$[2,4]: [12,23] -> 12$$
$$[4,6]: [23,15] -> 15$$

I leave it to you to complete the procedure.

Comment: Then I have to add them ? so for the upper 23+23+15+33= 94 and for the lower 15+12+6+6= 39 ?

Comment: Yes, those are the sums that would then be multiplied by $  \ \Delta x \ = \ 2 \ $ .